# How to change the styles of an element using typescript - Angular - primeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have this component from primeNG. I want it to have a width of 90% when `showInstallationValidate` is `true` and 50% when `showInstallationValidate` is `false`.

First I tried to apply the changes using style but it did not work.

```
 <p-sidebar #sidebar [(visible)]="sidebarDetailSelected" [style]="{width: showInstallationValidate ? '90%' : '60%'}"
  position="right">
```

I'm trying it from the typescript but it also gives me errors

HTML

```
<p-sidebar #sidebar  [(visible)]="sidebarDetailSelected" position="right">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">Datos de declarante</ng-template>
    <gestion-inst-gestor-details *ngIf="!showInstallationValidate" (show)="onShow($event)"></gestion-inst-gestor-details>
    <gestion-inst-gestor-validate *ngIf="showInstallationValidate" ></gestion-inst-gestor-validate>
</p-sidebar>
```

TS

```
@ViewChild('sidebar') sidebar!: Sidebar;

  sidebarDetailSelected = false;
  showInstallationValidate = false;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.showInstallationValidate) {
      this.sidebar.containerViewChild.nativeElement.style.width = '90%';
    }
  }

  onShow(event: boolean) {
    console.log(event);
    this.showInstallationValidate = event;
    if (this.showInstallationValidate) {
      this.sidebar.containerViewChild.nativeElement.style.width = '90%';
    }
  }
```

How can I fix it? Thank you very much

Comment: It is strange it didn't work when you tried template-based solution. `[style.width]="yourVariable + 'px'"` definitively works, never tried to give a ternary but it should work.

Did you try to set manually (through devtools) width to 50% / 90% and see an actual difference, or maybe your DOM is built in a way that this property has no visible effect ?

Comment: This is not a forum for telepaths; we don't know what your error messages are saying. Perhaps you'd like to read them yourself, or even share them so we could do that?

Comment: If I use it without the ternary operator it does take the dimensions:

`<p-sidebar #sidebar [(visible)]="sidebarDetailSelected" position="right" [style]="{ width: '95%' }">`.

From what I've seen in the console the ternary doesn't work because the sidebar always appears as undefine, I don't really understand why, that's why I wanted to try it from typescript but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: When I use: `this.sidebar.containerViewChild.nativeElement.style.width = '90%';` It tells me that both `containerViewChild` and `nativeElement` 'does not exist on type 'Sidebar''. I changed `@ViewChild('sidebar') sidebar!: Sidebar` to `@ViewChild('sidebar') sidebar!: ElementRef` and it doesn't work either, but it doesn't get errors, it just doesn't take the measurements when resizing.

Comment: Thanks, that was insightful. The template binding, however, works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/3oaodd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fsidebar-basic-demo.html.

Comment: Regarding your attempts to make it work through code-behind: just like the error message says, `Sidebar` does not have a member called `containerViewChild`: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/sidebar/sidebar.ts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you are using an entire object in the style binding, you should be using `[ngStyle]`, not just `[style]`

Comment: Nope, not in PrimeNG: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/6601. I mean, yes if you wanted the styles to be applied directly to the `p-sidebar` which is rarely the case. Here you actually want them to be applied to the child `div.p-sidebar` and you do it by binding to the `Sidebar.style` property, and the component passes it to the `div.p-sidebar`s `[ngStyle]`.